# recursive function to insert multidimensional array into mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an app that needs to store a multidimensional array into several mysql tables. When iterating through the array i need to find specific keys , insert the value into the database and pass the created DB ID to the child element in the array. For instance if there is a key "unit" find it , get the title , insert into database, return the id , pass that id to the next iteration. In the next iteration i get the id from the unit and search for a lesson , save the lesson with the unit id.

This is the hierarchy of the array.

Unit
-Lesson
-Quiz
--Question
---Answers

Here is an example of the output of the post form. There are randomly generated ids because the form is created dynamically by the user. Should i stick with for loops or use recursion to solve my problem? If recursion is possible here any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
Array
(
[unit] => Array
    (
        [fa53a225-e10c-408b-ad98-f3be26670587] => Array
            (
                [title] => Unit 1
                [lesson] => Array
                    (
                        [ae89d2bd-bb06-42ed-be5d-76d450fa1d68] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => Lesson 1
                            )

                        [79245a3a-e3e8-4aa2-9b5b-35cef4740d93] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => Lesson 2
                            )

                        [34c30554-3b4c-4c5f-b398-4dbc7a2f2d00] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => Lesson 3
                            )

                        [28241d75-1733-47e1-aa34-133bc71ef382] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => Lesson 4
                            )

                    )

                [quiz] => Array
                    (
                        [e93b5973-e13d-4a2d-a60a-4f86721b8f5a] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => Quiz 1
                                [question] => Array
                                    (
                                        [5e9d4f74-af08-430d-a405-e4d5464aff4a] => Array
                                            (
                                                [title] => Question 1
                                                [type] => truefalse
                                                [answer] => false
                                            )

                                        [b848cd75-bae4-44dd-99b0-ba041cd74b87] => Array
                                            (
                                                [title] => Question 2
                                                [type] => truefalse
                                                [answer] => true
                                            )

                                        [f5c72134-2de2-4fc4-8601-1776e43461e9] => Array
                                            (
                                                [title] => Question 3
                                                [type] => multiple
                                                [correct] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => 0
                                                        [1] => 1
                                                    )

                                                [answer] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => answer 1
                                                        [1] => answer 2
                                                        [2] => answer 3
                                                        [3] => 
                                                        [4] => 
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [a8a42316-f5fb-4b44-bd41-e19e8f3fb8e0] => Array
            (
                [title] => Unit 2
                [lesson] => Array
                    (
                        [b438f957-7386-4202-8ff0-61fcdb020ba6] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => Lesson 1
                            )

                        [c6513c26-2d2f-4835-8fe7-9f4c82ea459d] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => Lesson 2
                            )

                        [d6853af6-e3a8-4e17-9df8-eeddb5859483] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => Lesson 3
                            )

                    )

                [quiz] => Array
                    (
                        [96c1b4c2-1e00-4702-9064-25fcea6e10bb] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => Quiz 1
                                [question] => Array
                                    (
                                        [fc44b82e-089c-47b0-8404-9c12a9ecb2d6] => Array
                                            (
                                                [title] => question 1
                                                [type] => truefalse
                                                [answer] => true
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
)
```

Comment: Do you know the maximum depth of the structure?

Comment: Yes , it ends at answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer recursion, as more flexible approach

```
$structure = ["Unit"=>
                      ["Lesson"=>[],
                       "Quiz"=>
                               ["Question"=>
                                            ["Answers"=>[]]]]];

function insertItems($array, $parent_db_id, $structure) {

   // at first step $object_name=Unit, at second Lesson, quiz
   foreach ($structure as $object_name=>$next_level_structure) {

     // loop through objects (at first step units, at second Lessons, quizes)
     foreach ($array[$object_name] as $object_id=>$object) {

       // ... insert in db $object_id, $object['title'], $parent_db_id etc
       // retrieve $inserted_db_id ...

       // next recursion level if next level not empty
       if ($next_level_structure) {
          insertItems($object, $inserted_db_id, $next_level_structure);
          }
       }  
     }

}

insertItem($data, null, $structure);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How do  I differentiate if it is a unit / lesson / question or quiz to know which table to use. For testing the function i just put the $object_id as the $inserted_db_id , this prints out the id of the first unit and then i get an error : " Undefined index: unit "

Comment: Ok, i got it. when calling insertItems($object, $inserted_db_id, $structure); for the next level structure just replaced $structure with $next_level_structure so it continiues to go through . Thanks for the answer. Really helped!!